# Can a variable with a generic parameter as the base class be used to reference a variable with a generic parameter as the derived class in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

DataModel Class Inheritance:

```
BaseLine
Line:  BaseLine
PolyLine: BaseLine
```

Render Class Inheritance:

```
BaseRenderComp<T> where T : BaseLine
LineRenderComp: BaseRenderComp<Line>
PolyLineRenderComp: BaseRenderComp<PolyLine>
```

I want to know if there is a way to represent the objects of LineRenderComp and PolyLineRenderComp together, like below, but the below method does not work now.

```
if(renderComp is BaseRenderComp<BaseLine> baseRenderComp) {
do something....
}
```

And I want to this way be equal to these two `if` condtions：

```
if(renderComp is LineRenderComp lineRenderComp) {
do something....
}

if(renderComp is PolyLineRenderComp polyLineRenderComp) {
do something....
}
```

Comment: You may need to resort to something like [IsAssignableTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignableto?view=net-8.0), maybe?

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the last two `if`'s with a single `if`?

Comment: @Artur Yep, I want to use one `if` instead of two.

Comment: @Fildor But I still need to use some kind methods to use one variable to represent two objects.

Comment: Ah, oh no. Doesn't work as I thought at first. Although `PolyLine` is-a `Line`, `BaseRenderComp<Line>`, `BaseRenderComp<PolyLine>` and `BaseRenderComp<BaseLine>` are completely separate and independent types.

Comment: You could however have the two in question implement a common interface ...

Comment: ^^ What I meant above: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QfMpw7

Comment: @Fildor Thanks a lot! I understand why I can't use `BaseRenderComp<BaseLine>` to represent objects of `BaseRenderComp<Line>` and `BaseRenderComp<PolyLine>`. If I could, then I could put an Orange into a Banana list, as the second answer to the above question mentioned. I think your method is a good way to achieve my goal. The only downside is that I will introduce a one-use common interface.